# How handle can't reach host on Titanium appcellerator

Tags: javascript, web, titanium, titanium-mobile

I used this code example to send a GET request on my HTTP server.

```
var url = "http://myserver.com/resource.html";
     var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
         // function called when the response data is available
         onload : function(e) {
             alert('success');
         },
         // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
         onerror : function(e) {
             Ti.API.debug(e.error);
             alert('error');
         },
         timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
     });
     // Prepare the connection.
     client.open("GET", url);
     // Send the request.
     client.send();
```

If the request has a success response the onload is correctly called.
If the request has an error response like, 404 Not Found, the onerror is correctly called.
But if the host is unreacheble both onload and onerror are called.
How I can do for handle host unreacheble?

Comment: What you are doing getting the json data from html file.This looks to me strange

Comment: sorry this.responseText is a cut&paste refuse

Answer (score 0):

I've noted that this behaviour is made only on browser. On Android device all work well